# Flex Mobile Sizing & Positioning With DPI Changes

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, dpi

Ok, I'm building a Flex Mobile project right now for iOS. It is a prototype video player using an ANE (Native Extension). The video player will be used later on in a much larger project.

Now, the issue I am having is sizing and positioning, and I believe the issue is because I am setting an applicationDPI of 160 for the project.

Here is what is happening. The ANE is, essentially, a glorified StageWebView that has a ton of extra features built into it and offers no GUI (the main draw over using StageWebView). This item is positioned in the global space like StageWebView and no matter what I try, I cannot get it to position and size correctly. This is, essentially, what is responsible for the sizing and placement of the player

```
this.height = 50% of stage
this.width = 50% of stage
this.globalPoint:Point = this.localToGlobal(new Point(0,0));

this.viewPort = new Rectangle (this.globalPoint.x,this.globalPoint.y,this.width,this.height - 35); //35 = height of controls
this.videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer(this.stage,this.viewPort); //VideoPlayer(stage:Stage,viewPort:Rectangle)
```

Now, in my head, this looked to be perfect. It's not in the display list, but to the end user, it would appear like it was. It would stay glued to 0,0 of the parent class (along with the help of a Resize function, of course) and the video would be the size of the appropriate area.

I was wrong. It was positioned way off and sized far larger on my Retina iPad. After collecting a ton of data and doing the math, I found a constant of 4/3 that everything seemed to be off by. The DPI change for the iPad is 3/2 (160 -> 240) so I don't think that is the issue.

I also came up with this simple equation for compensating for the DPI shift.

```
newValue = (oldValue / (DeviceManager.applicationDPI / FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.applicationDPI) ); //DeviceManager.applicationDPI is a static getter that returns either 160, 240, or 320 based on Adobe's predefined ranges
```

I have not tested this on an iPad 1/2 or iPhone yet, but I'm worried that my magic constant is, in reality, just the aspect ratio being factored in to things.

Does anyone have any idea why the positioning is all messed up? It's not the localToGlobal, because even manually entering values that should have worked led to disaster.

Comment: Did you set an ApplicationDPI value in the application tag of your Flex app?  I strongly recommend that you do not do this; as it will always return the value you set instead of the real ApplicationDPI.  Beyond that, I find this question very confusing and I'm not sure exactly what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, I set it in the application tag. There is no other way to do this. My DeviceManager.applicationDPI call does not return this value (the FlexGlobals call does); it manually determines what the true applicaticationDPI is. What I am trying to figure out is why my seemingly good positioning and sizing does not equate to where they should, but dividing by 4/3 gives me what I am looking for.

Comment: My fear of the constant being tied to aspect ratio appears to be correct. Everything is all screwed up again on iPhone.

Comment: I strongly recommend you setting the ApplicationDPI.  It just causes lots of layout issues.  I recommend, instead, writing your own layout code based on the height/width available to you in your component.  It does seem to work okay to chose different assets based on ApplicationDPI; but that is negated if you are setting it to a hard coded value for your application.

Comment: The application is roughly 10,000 lines of custom working code. The amount of work that would be required to set up different UI configs for the three ApplicationDPIs is well out of scope for the project. Setting to 160 and using vector images in the interface is the best option, even though I have had a few issues regarding sizing and positioning (which have all been fixed by the "newValue" line in my OP until now)

Comment: I still strongly recommend writing layout code on a component by component basis based on the space you have to display the elements in.  That doesn't usually have anything to do with DPIs.  I am a big fan of using vector images; although "Best Practices" tell us that you should have one image for each DPI in order to accommodate for skewing differences.  I have solved that issue by using square assets whenever possible.

Comment: Again, this is not possible. If we had known at the beginning that DPI differences would cause so many issues, we would have used a full layout engine with different font sizes and images for each DPI setting. At this point, it would take another full week just to do that for this project. All I wanted to know is why setting a custom DPI caused so many issues with sizing and positioning

Comment: I find the question very confusing and did not understand what you were asking.  You may consider rewording the question to be more clear w/ regards to why setting a custom DPI causes so many issues w/ sizing and positioning.  As best I understand it; a lot of Flex Framework components use FXG assets under the hood based on the applicationDPI value.  I believe using the 160 dpi assets on a non-160dpi screen causes oddities.  The formulas the Flex framework uses for re-sizing things; just don't seem up to par.  You'd have to dig through framework code for more.

Comment: The issue seems to have been caused by a very recent upgrade to AIR 3.3 SDK. Using 3.1, everything seems to be behaving as normal. Either there is something wrong with the Mac 3.3 SDK or my install was not done correctly/completely. Either way, this seems to have been solved.